# How to merge the rows based on the one column in SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, pivot

I've made the below SQL script, but am still struggling with merging the two rows into one.

**EDIT 25.05.2023**

The first script derives data from the table **TB.ORDER.O**. There are two order types which are **SHIPPED_ORDER** and **RETURN_ORDER**.

```
select
    O.ISSUE_ID "Case ID",
    O.ORDER_ID,
    O.ORDER_TYPE
from 
  TB.ORDER O 
where
  O.CREATED_DATE > '01-Jul-20'
  and O.ORDER_TYPE in ('SHIPPED_ORDER','RETURN_ORDER')
```

| Case ID | ORDER_TYPE | ORDER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CASE 1 | SHIPPED_ORDER | Shipped Order AAA |
| CASE 1 | RETURN_ORDER | Returned Order AAB |
| CASE 2 | SHIPPED_ORDER | Shipped Order CCC |
| CASE 2 | RETURN_ORDER | Returned Order CCD |

The order types I needed to transform into two columns, so I wrote the below script:

```
SELECT
    O.ISSUE_ID "Case ID",
    O.ORDER_TYPE,
    CASE
        WHEN O.ORDER_TYPE = 'SHIPPED_ORDER' THEN O.ORDER_ID
    END AS SHIPPED_ORDER,
    CASE
        WHEN O.ORDER_TYPE = 'RETURN_ORDER' THEN O.ORDER_ID
    END AS RETURN_ORDER
from 
  TB.ORDER O 
where
  O.CREATED_DATE > '01-Jul-20'
  and O.ORDER_TYPE in ('SHIPPED_ORDER','RETURN_ORDER')
```

This is the result I currently get:

| Case ID | SHIPPED_ORDER | RETURN_ORDER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CASE 1 | Shipped Order AAA |  |
| CASE 1 |  | Returned Order AAB |
| CASE 2 | Shipped Order CCC |  |
| CASE 2 |  | Returned Order CCD |

This what I would like to have:

| Case ID | SHIPPED_ORDER | RETURN ORDER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CASE 1 | Shipped Order AAA | Returned Order AAB |
| CASE 2 | Shipped Order CCC | Returned Order CCD |

I've tried to use a `CASE` expression as shown in the code, but still it doesn't work as I want.

Comment: Please avoid images. You can write tables as formatted text, which makes it easier to copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply aggregation: the `MAX` aggregate function will allow null values to be absorbed by non-null ones. Remember to add your selected non-aggregated columns into your `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT O.ISSUE_ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN O.ORDER_TYPE = 'SHIPPED_ORDER' 
                THEN O.ORDER_ID
           END) AS SHIPPED_ORDER,
       MAX(CASE WHEN O.ORDER_TYPE = 'RETURN_ORDER' 
                THEN O.ORDER_ID
           END) AS RETURN_ORDER
FROM TB.ORDER O 
WHERE O.CREATED_DATE > '01-Jul-20'
  AND O.ORDER_TYPE IN ('SHIPPED_ORDER','RETURN_ORDER')
GROUP BY O.ISSUE_ID
```

**Output**:

| ISSUE_ID | SHIPPED_ORDER | RETURN_ORDER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CASE 1 | Shipped Order AAA | Returned Order AAB |
| CASE 2 | Shipped Order CCC | Returned Order CCD |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/jN6yer1Q).

Comment: Great answer, but remember tables have _columns_. not fields. Still upvoted.

Comment: Researched and discovered the difference between the two yesterday, when you were commenting on that post. Must say still need to get used: till now I've used the two terms interchangeably, although that's a kind of technical inaccuracy. Thanks for remarking.

Comment: Many people still use them interchangeably, but when row data types are involved it quickly becomes very confusing.

Comment: Thank you lemon for your answer. Although the solution didn't worked. I edited my question, because I think I wasn't clear about the two types of data. SHIPPED_ORDER RETURN_ORDER are originally rows of the column ORDER_TYPE. So maybe that would be helpful. Could you take a look. I was also thinking about using PIVOT expression instead of CASE WHEN.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Is it Postgres?

Comment: Minor fix by removing `ORDER TYPE` from the selection and the `GROUP BY` clause. Try it now.

Comment: DBMS is Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

Comment: It has finally worked :) After I removed ORDER TYPE from the selection and left GROUP BY O.ISSUE_ID. Thanks a lot :)